# Is there a python version of qTuio?

Tags: pyqgis

Is there a python version of qTuio?

qTuio is implemented in C++. However, I am currently trying to use pyqgis due to problems with C++ environment (I cannot even create a raster layer).

Answer (score 1):

I cannot tell you but perhaps [pyTuio](https://code.google.com/p/pytuio/) may be of some use to you. It is defined as **"A Python library that understands the TUIO protocol"** and describes the installation and a basic use.